# XCode 8.3 , Unable to open Storyboard. It opens on XCode 8.2.1 though

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode8

Updated my machine to El Capitan 
XCode 8.3 is not opening one storyboard from my project storyboards 
XCode 8.2.1 is opening that storyboard

I am getting following errors

(null): Did not find storyboard named "Wall" referenced from Main.storyboard

could not read data from '/Users/Xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SikkaNet2-gaworyaefclfxpbfdbykpadvzxcu/Build/Intermediates/SikkaNet2.build/Debug-AWS-UAT-SIKKA-PROD-iphonesimulator/SikkaNet2.build/Wall-SBPartialInfo.plist': The file “Wall-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/XXX/Desktop/Code/XXX/View/Wall/Wall.storyboard: error: The document "Wall.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)
    Recovery Suggestion: Check the console log for additional information.

Comment: Updated to XCode 8.3.1 too and getting the same error. Console error is here `Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`

Comment: Ahmed, please file a bug on https://bugreport.apple.com and attach your storyboard, and mention this Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue of xcode 8.3, thank's **apple** for this. to fix it, create new `group` and move `*.storyboard && *.xib` to it.